# Which mode of hadoop and HDFS needed to be instlled?

Tags: hadoop

I am a beginner to hadoop and HDFS, Now I have a situation where I need to connect 3 different PC having a file, NIFI and Hadop+HDFS.
Machine 1 : Will have a .csv file
Machine 2(Personal laptop): Will have my NIFI running to it.
Machine 3(Running at my office) : will have Hadoop+HDFS in it.

Now I would like to send a csv file from machine 1 to my database running on machine 3 using nifi which is running on machine 2.

I connect to machine 3 using ssh connection which is basically a router at my office.

Question:How can I connect to machine 3 from machine 2 which has nifi which can send the file to my hadoop hbase.
Should I use public key as configuration or should I use a different setup or server?

My configuration of files of haddo and hdfs are as follows

> hbase-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>
 <property>
<name>hbase.rootdir</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
<value>2222</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
<value>/home/hadoop/zookeeper</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
<property>
<name>hbase.wal.provider</name>
<value>filesystem</value>
</property>
 <property>
<name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
<value>./tmp</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

> core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
<value>/home/hdoop/tmpdata</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

> hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>


<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.name.dir</name>
<value>file:///home/hadoop/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.data.dir</name>
 <value>file:///home/hadoop/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Look in to the configuration files and let me know where I need to change the properties and also I have install til now the psudo distributed mode HDFS in machine 3.

Comment: Hi, there are too many questions here to answer - can you post one question at a time to get the relevant help?

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo distributed and fully distributed aren't any different.

You say only machine 3 has HDFS. Therefore only it needs to be running a Namenode and Datanode, setup in a distributed fashion, meaning that external clients will be able to communicate with it.

More specifically, no config file should be using `localhost` and should instead use LAN IP or hostnames

Comment: So you mean the public ip of machine 3 and its port should be the config on machine 3?

Comment: All the `core-site.xml` files should be the same. At least for `fs.default.name`. They should all use the IP/Hostname of the machine running the namenode process. Same for `hbase.rootdir` in hbase-site.xml ... You only need one `hdfs-site` on the namenode/datanode machine

Comment: i understand this as for example my machine 3 has its private Ip as 192.168.0.1 and for the same machine its public IP is 192.10.11.12 with port 2022. Now i should i replace the the localhost with machine 3 public IP so that i can access it from anywhere using nifi?

Comment: I don't know what port 2022 is, but the namenode should be port 9000 on both private and public address spaces. Use whichever IP is correct for your network boundaries.

Comment: 2022 is the public port. I conect the PC which is running in my office thru ssh from my  personal laptop like ssh name@192.10.11.12 -p 2022. So I guess I need to prove this IP and port in config file so that I can send file using nifi running on my personal laptop  to that machine isn't it?